# What is the best way to store array of strings as node property in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a requirement in which a property key can contain multiple values.
How do I store them as property in Neo4j?

Ex:
Person node has properties like: 'name', 'age' and 'interests'
The 'interests' property can can contain more than one strings(array of strings).

What is the best approach to store 'interests'?
I think I don't want to complicate this by adding more nodes. Instead I want to keep all properties in the same Person node.

Also, it will be good if I can search a Person node by any one item in the 'interests' property.

Store as one string separated by some special chars?
Store as array of strings for a property? if so how do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered reading the manual?  Here is the section on cypher collections - http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/syntax-collections.html

Comment: Thanks, looks like I can json encode list of values and store as one value of a property. Is it possible to search(or match) by one of the value in the property?

Comment: You could certainly store json as a string but then you really would not be able to exploit the database when searching.  Like @Brian says, if you are going to search on the 'interests' you are likely best served by making them first class citizens in your model.

Answer (score 5):

You can store an array of strings as a property and that's what I might suggest if you want to simply see a list of interests when working with a particular `Person` node:

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-property-values.html#_arrays

If you want to look up people by interests, however, I would strongly suggest thinking about storing them as nodes.  With the `MERGE` cypher command it can be quite easy to manage them, and it should be more performant.

Comment: Brian, I have similar question.
For example I have two type: Country and Person.
Object of Country type have parameter 'GDP'. This parameter is array of pair (year,GDP).
Object of Person type have parameter weight. This parameter is array of pair (year,weight).
Fnd I have different relationships, one of them for example PRESIDENT with begin and end dates

How can I search with this composite parameters and how, for example, find Person who was president and had smallest weigth in presidential term

or where can I read information about my task